# Concurrent LinkedList vs ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need a concurrent list that is thread safe and at the same time is best for iteration and should return exact size.
I want to to store auction bids for an item. So I want to be able to

1. retrieve the exact number of bids for an item
2. add a bid to a item
3. retrieve all the bids for a given item.
4. Remove a bid for a item

I am planning to have it in a 
`ConcurrentHashMap<Item, LinkedList<ItemBid>>` -- LinkedList is not thread safe but returns exact size
`ConcurrentHashMap<Item, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ItemBid>>` - concurrentlinked queue is thread safe but does not guarantee to return exact size

Is there any other better collection that will address the above 4 points and is thread safe.

Comment: What do you mean precisely with "exact size"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well arguably in a thread-safe collection *or* map you cannot guarantee the "consistency" of the size, meaning that the "happen-before" relationship between read and write operations will not benefit your desired use case, where a read operation on the size should return a value reflecting the exact state from the last write operation (**N.B.**: improved based on comments - see below).

What you *can* do if performance is not an issue is to use the following idiom - either:

- `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<YourKeyType, YourValueType>());`
- `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<YourType>());`

You'll then also need to explicitly synchronize over those objects.

This will ensure the order of operations is consistent at the cost of blocking, and you should get the last "right" size at all times.

Comment: The thread-safe collections do establish _happens-before_.  That's an important part of what "thread-safe" means.  I think that what you are trying to say is that thread-safety is not _composeable_.  That is to say, even if every object in your application is thread-safe, that does not make your _application_ thread safe.  Just because a collection is "thread-safe" does not in any way guarantee that what one application thread puts into the collection is what some other application thread expects to find there.

Comment: Assuming, this collection will be part of a large auction system taking millions of bids a day, so performance would a concern. Using a decorator to synchronize my collection would impact performance.

Comment: @james_large fair point, thanks for your clarification. I should probably edit this when I'm back home :)

Comment: @Kar understood but then, how come do you need the "exact" size at any given time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#size()). It is blocking (as apposed to the CLQ) but size is maintained and not scanned like the CLQ.

Comment: I assure you, the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is certainly thread safe. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html It says there `BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. `.